# Maintain same speed for a body in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I want to maintain same speed for a body in LIBGDX. When I run the game in low resolution phone, the character body is moving at a slow rate. Whereas , when I run the game in high resolution mobile, the character is moving at a fast rate. I wanted the speed to be constant no matter what the mobile is.

This is my code,

```
  if (gamehero.heroBody.getLinearVelocity().x > -1.5f) {
  Vector2 RUNNER_JUMPING_LINEAR_IMPULSE = new Vector2(1.4f, 0);
  gamehero.heroBody.applyLinearImpulse(RUNNER_LEFT_LINEAR_IMPULSE, gamehero.heroBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
   }
```

This is the code I execute when the "right"key control is pressed. To maintain the speed for all resolution, I tried the below code by referrring this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862028/speed-in-game-with-libgdx)

```
 float s = Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 60f);
 gamehero.setPosition(gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().x + 50f*0.5f,0) ;
```

When I use the above code, the body is not moving at all. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Normally, the game should look and act the same on every device. Have you looked at [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)?

Comment: Does viewport have an effect in speed of the body @Marius

Comment: Normally, the speed should be all the same. So just try it and add for example a `StretchViewport` to your stage.

Comment: I am using viewport in my game already @Marius

Comment: Then I can't see your problem. On bigger devices, your bodies should scale, which leads to the same speed.